# Importing an existing Eclipse project into MyEclipse workspace

Tags: eclipse, myeclipse

I am trying to import an existing project into my ECLIPSE wORKSPACE .
While importing the project into Eclipse using the 
(Existing Projects into Workspace ) option from eclipse , 
i have got the following screen shot .

[image: screen shot]

Now my question is What does the checkbox mean here 
(Copy Projects into Workspace )

Please refer to the screen here

http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=n4tcua&s=7

What is the impact if we check or uncheck the checkbox 
Need your help on this .

Thanks .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think he is more concerned about the check box, The check box tells you wether to create a copy of all the resources in the project you are importing to your workspace or not, and if you keep it unchecked it will just create a .classpatha and .project file ( basically a project ) with all the resources refering to original location.

Answer (score 1):

The screen asked you to select the root directory and not just a single project. It then displays all the projects present in that directory. You can then allow to choose between the projects to import to the workspace.

Comment: Thank you Naved , so you mean to say that If we select the Copy Projects into Workspace Checkbox , it will copy all the Projects present into our Eclipse Workspace , so i guess always this chekbox should be selected only . please guide me if i followed it correctly ??

Comment: yes, if you check this, it will copy the selected project into the workspace (with no reference). It will list all the projects (.project) present in the selected directory and thus you can copy multiple project to the workspace.